# Make Facebook Graph Request inside a RxJava Observable

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, rx-java

I have a method that uses the Facebook Android SDK to asynchronously get the current user info. But when the user info are retrieved I have to convert the profile picture URL to a Bitmap, and I have to do this asynchronously too. So to download the profile pic I used RxJava:

```
public void getCurrentUserInfo(){

    GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(fbAccessToken,
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(final JSONObject facebookUser, GraphResponse response) {

                    try {

                        final UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
                        userInfo.setFacebookId(facebookUser.getString("id"));
                        userInfo.setName(facebookUser.getString("name"));
                        userInfo.setEmail(facebookUser.getString("email"));
                        userInfo.setGender(facebookUser.getString("gender"));


                        //RxJava Observable subscription
                        downloadProfilePicture(facebookUser.getJSONObject("picture")
                                                           .getJSONObject("data")
                                                           .getString("url"))
                                              .subscribe(new Action1<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call (Bitmap bitmap){

                            userInfo.setProfilePic(bitmap);

                            });


                    }catch (JSONException jsonException){

                        jsonException.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", requestFields);
    graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
    graphRequest.executeAsync();
}
```

My observable:

```
 public Observable<Bitmap> downloadProfilePicture(final String... url){

   return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Bitmap>() {

       @Override
       public void call(Subscriber<? super Bitmap> subscriber) {

           if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) { //2

               try {

                   InputStream inputStream = new java.net.URL(url[0]).openStream();
                   Bitmap profilePic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                   subscriber.onNext(profilePic); //4
                   subscriber.onCompleted(); //5

               } catch (IOException e) {

                   subscriber.onError(e); //6
               }
           }
       } //1
   }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

My question is, is there a way to create a single Observable that makes the GraphRequest and with the result, automatically downloads the profile picture? ( Maybe using Operators?)

Comment: Why do you want to add a bitmap to an user object? 
I would store the url to the bitmap into the user object and only load the bitmap if needed with glide or picasso direct into the view.

Comment: @RobertHilse, this is a great approach! I was really uncomfortable with the fact that I was loading the bitmaps in the user info, and I forgot about the Picasso library :-)

Comment: I switched to glide, it's for small images faster and uses less recsources and you can handle it in a similiar way:
http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Answer (score 1):

Imho, additional to my comment some code how you could it make it a little prettier:

```
GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(fbAccessToken, "/me");
Observable.just(request.executeAndWait())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(new Func1<GraphResponse, UserInfo>() {
                @Override
                public UserInfo call(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
//parse and download your bitmap here
                    return parseGraphResponse(graphResponse);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<UserInfo>() {
...}
```

To be honest, I haven't tested this piece of code. It's the way I'm using the facebook sdk (4.6.0) to get places around a location where the node for facebook is "/search". But maybe you get an idea.

Comment: I believe your Observable.just(request.executeAndWait()) will execute the request right away and not wait for a subscriber... What you want to do is this: Observable.defer(()->Observable.just(request.executeAndWait())).